# How to pass and receive the user defined class in REST web services

Tags: web-services, rest

I am learning REST web services. i want to know is there any way to pass user defined class.i am not using spring here and i can able to pass JSON and Xml but is any way to pass user defined class. to pass JSON class am doing by following code.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url to REST services method");
List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", jsonObj.toString()));//some json object 
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
entity.setContentType("application/json");

httpPost.setEntity(entity);// here we set param as entity in httpPost

httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", contentType);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

in above example we have set the JSON object into httpPost, but if want to pass user defined class how to set in 'httpPost.setEntity' and what is the contentType i should mention.